# Popover - Removing interaction event on document (everything outside Popover content or target)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blueprintjs

I'm trying to use Popover component and have a case where I want to remove the click on document to close the popover. I want the user to click a close button within the content panel of my popover to close popover only.

I've tried using CLICK_TARGET_ONLY on interactionKind, but that doesn't allow me to use a close button in combination.

Do you know how I can achieve my desired behaviour?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This section may be useful: http://blueprintjs.com/docs/v1/#core/components/popover.opening---closing-popovers. Especially the part about `.pt-popover-dismiss`.